# Netmiko - confirmation in configuration mode

Tags: python, cisco, netmiko

I just start using netmiko and have a problem with one script. The script should delete a user and create another one. The problem that I have is with confirmation in configuration mode I don`t know how to handle it.

```
R1(config)#no username admin
This operation will remove all username related configurations with same name.Do you want to continue? [confirm]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you would a use an expect string.

```
output = net_connect.send_command(
    command_string=command,
    expect_string=r"Delete filename",
    strip_prompt=False,
    strip_command=False
)
output += net_connect.send_command(
    command_string="\n",
    expect_string=r"confirm",
    strip_prompt=False,
    strip_command=False
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ssh.send_command_timing()'`

like this:

```
ssh.send_command_timing(f'no username {user}')
```