# Netmiko - comfirming new configuration after save

Tags: python, config, netmiko

I am using netmiko to connect to a bunch of cisco controllers and change a small thing in their configuration.
After doing that I would like to save the configuration using the command `save config`, after which is asks `save config? y/n` and I would like to pass it `y`.
Sending the command `y` like so:

```
net_connect.send_command('save config')
net_connect.send_command('y')
```

doesn't work because the command `y` is unknown.

I've tried sending it like so:

```
net_connect.send_command('save config y')
```

But that just ignores the `y`.
I think the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67125071/netmiko-confirmation-in-configuration-mode) is helpful but I couldn't completely understand how to apply it to my problem.
Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out, turns out there is a [`save_config`](https://ktbyers.github.io/netmiko/docs/netmiko/cisco/index.html#netmiko.cisco.CiscoAsaSSH.save_config) method already implemented, Just running

```
net_connect.save_config()
```

Will save your configuratin.